# What is the normal fan speed on Mac computers

Tags: macos, xcode, crash

I have noticed that fan speed on my Mac is 499 rpm. Now this is a computer with installed OSX El Capitan, Xcode 8.2.1... I have noticed this when Xcode got crashed few weeks ago (the information was provided in Xcode crash log). Now, today, when it crashed again, I have noticed the same fan speed, which is 499...That is a bit odd I must say, because rpm are very low, and I got same number twice.

I wonder is this accurate info actually and what is the normal fan speed for MacPro3,1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "normal" speed for a fan in a computer.  The fan spins at a speed necessary to keep the CPU temp in the "normal operating range."<sup>1</sup>

For your particular Mac, the  [maximum operating temperature is about 82°C (180°F)](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-2670.html).  However, keep in mind that this does not factor in other components like heat from drives, adapters, etc. which may also go into calculating when a fan is engaged.

---

<sup>1</sup> See section 5 in [Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2400 Product Family Thermal/Mechanical Design Guide May 2012](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/design-guides/xeon-e5-2400-thermal-guide.pdf)

Comment: I was looking for an explanation why I always get 499 in the crash log actually...I suspect that what I am seeing in a crash log is not a real fan state. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: That "499" is a calculated value not an actual speed based on voltage sent by the SMC to the fan.

Comment: Okay, that at least explains something...

Comment: Also, 499 is the minimum RPM for some of the fans in a tower Mac Pro. Unless you are doing some very heavy lifting (video editing, rendering, etc), it's highly likely your fan speed is between 498 and 501.